# MySQL exact match acting like LIKE

Tags: mysql

Got an interesting problem with a simple MySQL query. I'm trying to do an exact match on the `id` field.

```
SELECT id
FROM tablename
WHERE id = '23'
```

Returns

```
id: 23
```

All is well and good until I do:

```
SELECT id
FROM repairs
WHERE id = '23abcd'
```

Returns

```
id: 23
```

Why on earth would it do this?!
`id` field is `int(10)` and the database is MyISAM utf8_general_ci.

Any thoughts?

Comment: switch to utf8_latin1_ci

Comment: This is the MySQL way. Instead of rejecting an apparently incorrect statement (because comparing a number with `'23abcd'` makes no sense) MySQL chooses to return "something". Most other DBMS would simply throw an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database has int field it will truncate the characters and only consider the numbers that's why you are getting 23 as return id.

Answer (score 0):

You are quoting the number in your query, so MySQL must convert it from a string to a number.   When it does that, it is using only the numeric part of the string.

I don't think the behavior is completely appropriate ( "23abcd".ToInt() should be NULL, I think), but that's what it does.

Comment: The query should simply be rejected (and most DBMS will do)

Answer (score 0):

As Fakhruddin said that `int` field truncates the value of characters. That's right. But you can prevent wrong values from being inserted in the first place by setting the `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` mode

```
mysql> SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';
```

One more thing is that you need to store your id as character strings(VARCHAR) if they contain letters.